# How to come up with minimal BufferedReader with Line numbers

Tags: java

Maybe somewhat of a newbie-ish question, but I need a `BufferedReader` that's also a `LineNumberReader` but with a specialization, i.e. the capability to limit the length of a line. I can't use said items from the JDK because they contain private fields and extraneous capabilities namely "marking" and "resetting" making it impossible without extraneous effort to simply override methods like `readline()`.

Is there a minimal implementation of a Buffered Reader that simply reads and counts lines available in the JDK or some other common library? I couldn't seem to find any. If not, would it be reasonable to simply delete out all the functionality having to do with "marking" and "resetting" so I can more easily make a simple Buffered Reader for my purposes; or better yet, is there an example of a buffered reader somewhere I can follow so I don't omit any crucial steps?

Again, I simply want a wrapper around a `Reader` that reads and counts lines with a small bit of added functionality in the `readLine()` method. It seems simple to do, I just don't want to miss any critical edge cases when dealing with buffering lines, and the JDK version seems to obfuscate this functionality with the added marking/resetting capability so that I can't discern quickly the necessary algorithms for simple line buffering. If anyone has some robust examples or knows of a library that does robust line buffering sans marking/resetting please share.

"Limit length of line" for this purpose means avoid a Denial of Service attack via overly-long line length that causes socket timeouts or causes `OutOfMemoryError` exceptions, etc.

Comment: Asking for a library or a code example is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: where do I ask that  then?

Comment: I would start with Google and see if you can find any code examples/tutorials that have something similar to what you're asking. If you try some of those examples and run into specific problems like an error or wrong output, you can ask that here. I've also seen when browsing Reddit people ask for decent libraries and there are plenty of subreddits involving Java programming.

Comment: You can simply start with a Reader implementation which uses an underlying [BufferedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html). See [InputStreamReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html). So the buffering part is already done by the input stream and you can concentrate on implementing the `readLine()` function by yourself without bothering about buffering.

Comment: What does “limit the length of a line” actually mean?  Are you truncating lines, or just assuming an implied newline after a certain number of characters?  If it’s the former, you can just use `bufferedReader.lines().map(s -> s.substring(0, Math.min(s.length(), maxLength)))`.

Comment: @VGR "limit length of line" is for purposes of avoiding an overflow attack, so it has to prevent excessive reads from underlying stream, and throwing an exception if exceeds a maximum. Also, this is JDK 7.

Comment: Note that nowadays when reading files one should use Javas new I/O library called **NIO**. It revolves around the classes `Files` and `Paths`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck at the Java 6 language level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution with help from @VGR and @slim:

```
package com.company.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;

public class LengthLimitedLineNumberReader {

  public static final int DEFAULT_MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 1024;
  private LineNumberReader delegate;
  private int readerMaxLineLen = DEFAULT_MAX_LINE_LENGTH;

  private int lineNumber = 0;

  public LengthLimitedLineNumberReader(LineNumberReader delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  public LengthLimitedLineNumberReader(LineNumberReader delegate, int readerMaxLineLen) {
    this(delegate);
    this.readerMaxLineLen = readerMaxLineLen;
  }

  public int getLineNumber() {
    return lineNumber;
  }

  public String readLine() throws IOException {

    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

    int c = delegate.read();
    if (c <= 0) {
      return null;
    }
    while (c >= 0 && c != '\n') {
      if (line.length() >= readerMaxLineLen) {
        throw new IOException("Exceeded max line length of " + readerMaxLineLen);
      }

      line.append((char) c);
      c = delegate.read();
    }

    lineNumber++;

    return line.toString();
  }

  public void close() throws IOException {
    delegate.close();
  }
}
```

Notes:

- I used the Decorator pattern suggested by @slim, but I didn't see the
  need to implement the Reader contract.

I used the basic code from @VGR, however:

- I didn't need to consume CRLF since that's taken care of already in a
  couple places by the delegate.
- I needed to track `lineNumber` locally
  because the delegate `LineNumberReader` increments in the `read()` method and thus fails to increment it in the case where line ends without an `\r` or `\n`.
- I need to throw an exception rather than continue processing when a line exceeds a max length. This is to avoid the case where an infinitely long line would cause a denial of service.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily extend the BufferedReader class as so:

```
import javafx.util.Pair;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

public class LimitLineReader extends BufferedReader {

    private int lineno = 0;
    private int maxlinelength;
    private String remainder = "";

    public LimitLineReader(Reader in, int sz) {
        super(in, sz);
    }

    public LimitLineReader(Reader in) {
        super(in);
    }

    public void setMaxLineLength(int len){
        this.maxlinelength = len;
    }


    public Pair<Integer,String> readLineTruncated() throws IOException {
        if( remainder.equals(""))
            remainder = super.readLine();
        String line = remainder.substring(0,Math.min(remainder.length(), maxlinelength));
        remainder = remainder.substring(Math.min(remainder.length(), maxlinelength));
        return new Pair<>(lineno++, line);
    }
}
```

This results in the following behaviour (as in this test should pass):

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException{
    String teststring = "12345\n1234567890\n1\n\n";

    LimitLineReader reader = new LimitLineReader(new StringReader(teststring));
    reader.setMaxLineLength(5);

    Pair<Integer, String> p;

    p = reader.readLineTruncated();
    assertEquals(p.getKey(), new Integer(0));
    assertEquals(p.getValue(), "12345");

    p = reader.readLineTruncated();
    assertEquals(p.getKey(), new Integer(1));
    assertEquals(p.getValue(), "12345");

    p = reader.readLineTruncated();
    assertEquals(p.getKey(), new Integer(2));
    assertEquals(p.getValue(), "67890");

    p = reader.readLineTruncated();
    assertEquals(p.getKey(), new Integer(3));
    assertEquals(p.getValue(), "1");

    p = reader.readLineTruncated();
    assertEquals(p.getKey(), new Integer(4));
    assertEquals(p.getValue(), "");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear. I updated my question, basically, I need to limit the reading of the stream to prevent vulnerability attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I would decorate `LineNumberReader` with a class of your own:

```
public class LengthLimitedLineNumberReader extends Reader {

     private LineNumberReader delegate;

     public LengthLimitedLineNumberReader(LineNumberReader delegate) {
          this.delegate = delegate;
     }

     @Override
     public int read() {
         return delegate.read();
     }

     // similar passthrough methods for Reader's abstract methods
     // and for `getLineNumber()` and any other methods of the 
     // delegate you need

     public String readLine() {
          // your own implementation of readLine()
          // using calls to delegate
     }
}
```

Because it's not a subclass of `BufferedReader` or `LineNumberReader` this isn't quite a drop-in replacement, but it comes close.

None of the methods in `BufferedReader` is `final` so you *could* replace the `extends Reader` with `extends BufferedReader` or `extends LineNumberReader`, and still implement it as a decorator; you would just need to take care that you're not accidentally exposing any methods of `BufferedReader` directly that clash with this implementation.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still basically starting from scratch here. I don't need to abide by any contracts, so there's no need to implement or decorate any JDK APIs. I was hoping for a low level implementation of "readLine" without read, skip, mark, reset, and all that stuff I don't need. Then I can add stuff I do need like line counting and preventing line overflow attacks, etc.

Comment: `readLine()` ain't rocket science. Just read one char at a time until you reach `\n`, `\r` or end of stream. The underlying buffered reader will take care of efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

It’s best to avoid subclassing unless necessary.  In this case, you don’t need to subclass;  just implement your own method, using a normal BufferedReader:

```
String readLine(BufferedReader reader)
throws IOException {
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

    int c = reader.read();
    while (c >= 0 && c != '\r' && c != '\n'
            && line.length() < MAX_LINE_LENGTH) {

        line.append((char) c);
        c = reader.read();
    }

    // Consume CRLF sequence, if any.
    if (c == '\r') {
        reader.mark(1);
        if (reader.read() != '\n') {
            reader.reset();
        }
    }

    return line.toString();
}
```

**Update:**

Fortunately, LineNumberReader support is also possible, since LineNumberReader allows manual changes to its line number:

```
String readLine(LineNumberReader reader)
throws IOException {
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();

    int c = reader.read();
    while (c >= 0 && c != '\r' && c != '\n') {

        line.append((char) c);

        if (line.length() >= MAX_LINE_LENGTH) {
            reader.setLineNumber(reader.getLineNumber() + 1);
            break;
        }

        c = reader.read();
    }

    // Consume CRLF sequence, if any.
    if (c == '\r') {
        reader.mark(1);
        if (reader.read() != '\n') {
            reader.reset();
        }
    }

    return line.toString();
}
```

Comment: Updated answer with LineNumberReader version of method.

Comment: This works well put in the decorator suggested by @slim. I'm pretty sure the underlying buffers are protected so long as the max length set in the LineNumberReader constructor is less than or equal to the max line length. Does that seem right?

Comment: The buffer length doesn’t matter.  No matter how much data there is to read, the buffer won’t overflow.  Worst case scenario, you might or might not read smaller amounts with each call to a `read` method.

Comment: True, the buffer is typically capped at a reasonable size. I was confusing that with the DoS issue. So, to solve that issue of a malicious feed neglecting to provide \n and \r and the possibility of DoS, I think all that's needed is to throw an exception if line exceeds length rather than carry on.